# How do i create then delete a temporary batch file? (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013, cmd

My predicament today is that i don't know how to create a temporary bat file ( cause cmd opens a million windows every once in a while, Idk why?) If anybody could help i would be very grateful.

Comment: Stop asking for pranks here, please

Comment: Suggest a legitimate purpose first.

Comment: For your information this isnt for a prank but an application i'm making for a friend who doesn't have decent internet at his house so he and his brother can play lan games together plus if i wanted to make a prank app that would be way to easy. My app is already glitchy enough as it is. oh and if you aren't going to suggest legitimate answers then please don't say anything. people have been telling me what i need to do without actually helping or even explaining first. One person ( @HansPassant has said to " . Many proper alternatives available, like not using cmd.exe at all but simplyrunning

Comment: that" If somebody can just tell me an actual answer on how to stop cmd opening 1 million cmds or create a temporary batch file i would be very greatful cause this has been &*%$ing me off for over 2 weeks and its  very annoying,  so please just help and tell me what to actually do

Comment: Btw @mojo Its for a lan app in which the user can edit the ssid and key then run the app

Comment: What do you need to do with the temporary bat file? Couldn't you just run whatever commands that the bat file would run in the script that created the bat file? Do you want them all to run simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

cmd opens a million windows because you have a batch file called cmd, or something along those lines.

```
dir c:\cmd.* /s /a
```

and see what it turns up.

Comment: this is probably more suited as a comment

Comment: And how would I do that, you may notice all my points have gone again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear about what you want to accomplish, but I assume you'll want all these windows to open at once.
Here's a skeleton that might get you started:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM   The third number is how many temp bat files will be created.
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (
    SET TMPFILE=%TEMP%\!RANDOM!!RANDOM!!RANDOM!.cmd
    ECHO !TMPFILE!

    REM   Put the stuff you want in the temp file here.
    REM   Echo it and append (>>) to the temp file.
    @ECHO ECHO Temp batch file '%%~0' > "!TMPFILE!"

    REM   Delete the temp file when it's finished.
    @ECHO DEL /Q "%%~0" >> "!TMPFILE!"


    REM   Invoke the temp file in a new window.
    START "" cmd /k "!TMPFILE!"
)
```

You may or may not wish to delete the file from within itself. You'll probably want to delete it somehow, but only after the temp script has finished running.